# Problems deploying a web application

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-applications

I am trying to deploy a web application to a remote server over which i have no control.

If I use FTP deployment from visual studio, I manage to get the files onto the server, but when I point my browser to the server, it gives me the standand error page:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error
>   Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error >settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being >viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running >on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote >machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file >located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag >should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  >configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

I have made shure that custom errors has mode="Off" as the text above suggests. No amount of refreshing or Cntl-F5-ing gives me anything other than the error page above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely is that the location you have put it is not setup as an IIS Application and this is required for the .net framework application to work correctly.

As you have no control on the server you won't be able to change the IIS settings, and so dropping .net onto the server isn't quite the xcopy deployment method Microsoft pushed lots.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the virtual directory is mapped to the publish location properly. Because your question tells changing the web.config has no impact.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your application on remote server isn't defined as application in IIS. This means that it can't find it 'code' resources(bin or App_Code directories) and customErrors setting is taken from parent web.config.